# regex in php remove citation from wiki text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-parsing

From the given sample text i want the text apart from the ones that are contained in [[]] and {{}}

Sample Text:

On 11 December 1988, aged just 15 years and 232 days, Tendulkar scored 100 not out in his debut [[first-class cricket|first-class]] match for [[Mumbai cricket team|Bombay]] against [[Gujarat cricket team|Gujarat]], making him the youngest Indian to score a century on first-class debut. He followed this by scoring a century in his first Deodhar and Duleep Trophy.
{{cite web|url=http://www.espnstar.com/cricket/international-cricket/news/detail/item136972/Sachin-Tendulkar-factfile/|title=Sachin Tendulkar factfile |publisher=www.espnstar.com|accessdate=3 August 2009}} He was picked by the Mumbai captain [[Dilip Vengsarkar]] after seeing him negotiate [[Kapil Dev]] in the nets, and finished the season as Bombay's highest run-scorer.He scored 583 runs at an average of 67.77, and was the sixth highest run-scorer overall{{cite web|url=http://blogs.cricinfo.com/link_to_database/ARCHIVE/1980S/1988-89/IND_LOCAL/RANJI/STATS/IND_LOCAL_RJI_AVS_BAT_MOST_RUNS.html|title=1988–89 Ranji season – Most Runs|publisher=Cricinfo|accessdate=3 August 2009}} He also made an unbeaten century in the [[Irani Trophy]] final,{{cite web|url=http://cricketarchive.com/Archive/Scorecards/52/52008.html|title=Rest of India v Delhi in 1989/90
|publisher=Cricketarchive|accessdate=3 August 2009}} and was selected for the tour of Pakistan next year, after just one first class season.

I tried this:

```
$patterns = ("/^{{*/", "/*}}$/" );$replacements = "";
  preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $parts);
  print_r($parts);
```

and this:

```
$parts = preg_replace("/\[(?:\\\\|\\\]|[^\]])*\]/", "", $ans_str);
```

and this too:

```
$pattern = ("/\[.*?\]/", "/\{.*?\}/");
  $ans = preg_replace($pattern, "", $parts);
```

It does not work.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// remove `{{cite}}` tags
$str = preg_replace('/\s*\{\{[^}{]*+\}\}\s*/', ' ', $str);

// remove links--including rollover text--leaving link text
$str = preg_replace('/\[\[(?:[^][|]*+\|)?+([^][]*+)\]\]/', '$1', $str);
```

**[see demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/24SeQ)**

Comment: Thanks for your efforts man, but if you read the first line of my query it says:  i want the text apart from the ones that are contained in [[]] and {{}}
Meaning for a sample text: "Some text [[not this]] this one included {{exclude this one}}". the output should be-> "Some text this one included" Kindly see the output of your demo.

Comment: So, instead of "...in his debut first-class match for Bombay against Gujarat, making him...", you want "...in his debut   match for   against  , making him..."?  Whatever floats your boat!

Comment: apparently, thats my custom need.

Comment: anyways man, i have modified your second one to suit my needs thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick

```
$str = "On 11 December 1988, ...";
$str = preg_replace('/\{\{.+\}\}/Us', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

U modifier is for ungreedy mode, which means stop the match as soon as possible (to avoid all citations being caught as one giant match).

EDIT: added the s modifier, see comments

Comment: It does for me when I try it, care to post a sample code on pastebin.com to reproduce it ?

Comment: @Lepi, there are several newlines in the sample text that aren't visible in the question as posted (I had to edit the question to see them).  That includes one inside the last `{{cite}}` tag, which (I think) is why the OP says your solution doesn't work.  You just need to add the `/s` modifier to your regex.  (The newlines aren't present in the Pastebin post either, so that doesn't help.)

Comment: @Alan: thanks, fixed. Rahul: the edited version should work fine

Answer (score -1):

the following two lines did the trick :

```
$str = preg_replace(/\s*\{{.*?\}}\s*/g, " ", $str);//to remove the curly braces and the text between them.
$str = preg_replace(/[\[(.)\]]/g, "", $str);//to remove the square braces.
```

Sorry it went wrong.